# What quality measures can be used to evaluate a density-based clustering algorithm?

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, data-mining

I have a weighted undirected graph, where weight is the similarity and range from 0 to 1.
I applied a density-based clustering method and get some clusters, with overlapping nodes (node can belong to more than one cluster), and with noise or outlier nodes ( node don't belong to any cluster).

Now, are there quality measures that works fine with this clustering result?

For example, one of measures I think about is Modularity Q, but I don't sure if it suitable for my graph or not.
Also if other measures such as internal density, node betweeness, converge and entropy can be used here ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There was one recently proposed:

- Moulavi, D., Jaskowiak, P. A., Campello, R. J. G. B., Zimek, A., & Sander, J. (2014).
   **Density-based clustering validation.**
   In Proceedings of the 14th SIAM International Conference on Data Mining (SDM), Philadelphia, PA.

Havn't read it in details yet, or tried it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is really match my need except the overlapping feature, it is not supported. Do you have idea if it will affect the result if I use it or not ? And thanks again :)

Comment: I don't know. I believe none of the measures handles this case well. You may need to average per point over all its assignments.